# Rails 5: Rendering a partial to the application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Within `views/layouts/application.html` I have the line `<%= yield %>`.  This line is ultimately replaced by views directly corresponding to controller actions without any problems.

In one of my controllers, I am trying to render a partial instead of the default behaviour:

```
def show
    @service_groups = ServiceGroup.where(deleted_at: nil)
    render partial: 'table', locals: {rows: @service_groups, headers: service_group_headers}
end
```

I'm using a partial in this way so that I can use the same basic table structure for various different database tables (across different controllers).

This `render partial` code doesn't seem to work with the `<%= yield %>` line in the application layout.  The partial code is just rendered on its own without the surrounding layout.

1. Why is this?
2. How do I rectify the problem?

Please let me know if I should be handling this a different way.

Thanks.

Comment: What if you created a `show.html.erb` for that controller and placed `render :partial` there? It should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that would work. Will confirm tomorrow. Just seems a bit of a waste to have so many files that don't actually do anything, but if it's Rails convention to do it that way, I will go with it.

Comment: It worked, thanks.

Comment: I'm gonna post this as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*migrating from comments*)

What if you created a `show.html.erb` for that controller and placed `render :partial` there? It should work.

Explanation: Partials are to be used from "big" views. So, they are not wrapped in the layout on purpose!